# Precurse with open() or .write()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to precurse a write function in python (I'm working with fasta files but any write function that works with text files should work)?
The only way I could think is to read the whole file in as an array and count the number of lines I want to start at and just re-write that array, at that value, to a text file.

I was just thinking there might be a write an option or something somewhere.

I would add some code, but I'm writing it right now, and everyone on here seems to be pretty well versed, and probably know what I'm talking about. I'm an EE in the CS domain and just calling on the StackOverflow community to enlighten me.

Comment: What do you mean by "precurse"?

Comment: like start at line 4 when writing (rather than 0)

Comment: you know how there is the .readline()? Is ther like a .readFromLine4()?

Comment: You can index into a file with `.seek()`, which may help!

Comment: ahhh, didnt think of that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to truncate a file from the start - i.e remove the first n lines.

Then no - there is no way you can do without reading in the lines and ignoring the lines - this is what I would do :

```
import shutil
remove_to = 5 # Remove lines 0 to 5
try:
    with open('precurse_me.txt') as inp, open('temp.txt') as out:
        for index, line in enumerate(inp):
             if index <= remove_to:
                  continue
             out.write(line)
     # If you don't want to replace the original file - delete this
     shutil.move('temp.txt', 'precurse_me.txt') 
 except Exception as e:
     raise e
```

Here I open a file for the output and then use [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil.move) to replace the input file only after the processing (the for loop) is complete. I do this so that I don't break the 'precurse_me.txt' file in case the processing fails. I wrap the whole thing in a try/except so that if anything fails it doesn't try to move the file by accident.

The key is the for loop - read the input file line by line; using the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to count the lines as they come in.
Ignore those lines (by using continue) until the index says to not ignore the line - after that simply write each line to the out file.

Comment: you know how there is the .readline()?  Is ther like a .readFromLine4()?

Comment: or couldnt i do something like for line in file: line = line + 1; if line > 4: everythingAfter4.append(line)?

Comment: @Norman - no there isn't a readfromline4(), but it is trivial to do. You don't need to do line = line + 1 - that is what the enumerate() does that for you. You don't have to write the file out if you don't want - I gave you an example of how to write back out to a file (and then rename it) - you can process the lines anyway you want.
If all you are going to do is to write the file back out (as I understood from your question), you don't need to append them to a list.